# http não é reconhecido no projeto Node Express

Tags: node.js

Meu projeto está dando essa mensagem de erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque será que meu projeto não está reconhecendo o meu http?

Eu sou novo, e ainda estou aprendendo a programar em node express.

Esse aqui é meu package.json;

```
{
  "name": "registre",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API",
  "main": "server/server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node/ ./server/server.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Wladimir",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "pg": "^7.4.3",
    "sequelize-cli": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.35",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.27.25",
    "sequelize": "^4.38.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Esse problema ai ta relacionado com typescript, porque no babel a mesma sintaxe não apresenta problema. Nao uso typescript ai nao sei qual o problema kkkk desculpe.

Comment: talvez o typescript precise está instalado globalmente no sistema operacional, sabe qual é o comando para ver qual é a versão do typescript que está instalado no meu pc?

Comment: `tsc -v`, mas acho que vc nao precisa usar o `as` só o `import http from 'http'` ja resolve.

Comment: estranho, meu typescript está instalado globalmente  `Version 3.0.1`

Comment: Então usa como eu falei, sem o as, nao tem necessidade nesse contexto. E o http é padrão dos pacotes.

Comment: deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82269/discussion-between-ams-and-wladyband).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como discutido em chat, problema na versão do pacote padrão do express. Fez se necessário a instalação do pacote compatível com a versão do `@types`.

`npm install @type/express` atual versão do `@types express@4.16.0`

`npm install express@4.16.0`

Problema solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde eu sei vc tem duas opções:

1. (Recomendado) Instalar a dependecia do @types/node com `npm install @types/node --save-dev`.
2. Criar um arquivo `index.d.ts` declarando uma definição pro modulo http. O arquivo pode ficar assim: 
   `declare module 'http`

Lembrando que essa segunda opção não vai adicionar o auto complete com os metodos do modulo.